# Problem 6. Barry Simon. A comprehensive course in analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ compact Hausdorff space in wich every $\left\{x\right\}$ is a Baire set and let $\mu$ be a Baire measure. 
Define $\mu_{pp}(A)=\sum_{x\in A}\mu(\left\{x\right\})$

(a) Prove that $\mu_{pp}$ is a pure point measure. I already proves!

(b) Prove that $\mu_{c}:=\mu-\mu_{pp}$ is a nonnegative continuous measure.
I already prove!

(c)If $\mu=\nu_c+\nu_{pp}$ with $\nu_{pp}$ and $\nu_{c}$ continuous, prove that $\nu_{pp}=\mu_{pp}$ and so $\nu_{c}=\mu_{c}$ (Correction. $\nu_{pp}$ is a pure point)

How prove (c)?

Comment: You have not quoted c) correctly. If $\nu_c$ and $\nu_{pp}$ are both continuous than $\mu$ itself is continuous.

Comment: oh! yes. 
$\nu_{pp}$ is pure point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C=\{x:\mu \{x\} \neq 0\}$ and $D=\{x:\nu_{pp} \{x\} \neq 0\}$, Verify the following for any measurable set $E$: $$\nu_c(E)=\nu_c(E\setminus C\cup D)=\mu (E\setminus C\cup D)-\nu_{pp}(E\setminus C\cup D)$$ $$=\mu_c (E\setminus C\cup D)+\mu_{pp} (E\setminus C\cup D)-\nu_{pp}(E\setminus C\cup D)$$ $$=\mu_c (E\setminus C\cup D)+0+0=\mu_c(E).$$ This proves that $\nu_c=\mu_c$ and it follows automatically that $\mu_{pp}=\nu_{pp}$.

Comment: Why $\mu_{pp}( (E\setminus C)\cup D)=0$?
I have this.
Sup. $\mu_{pp}( (E\setminus C)\cup D)>0$ then exists $x\in (E\setminus C)\cup D$ such that $\mu(x)>0$.
If $x\in E\setminus C$ then $x\not\in C$, implies $\mu(x)=0$ a contradiction.
If $x\in D.$ What is the contradiction?

Comment: @eraldcoil By $E\setminus C\cup D$ I meant $E\setminus (C\cup D)$, not $(E\setminus C)\cup D$

Comment: ah ok! thanks.
I see $\nu{pp}(E\setminus (C\cup D))=0$ but if $\nu{pp}(E\setminus (C\cup D))>0$ then exits $x\in E\setminus (C\cup D): \nu_{pp}(x)>0$ a contradiction because $x\in D^c$.
Similary, $\mu_{pp}(E\setminus (C\cup D))=0$.

But I still do not see $\nu_c(E)=\nu_c(E\setminus (C\cup D))$

Comment: @eraldcoil $C$ and $D$ are both countable sets and $\nu_c$ is a continuous measure. Hence $\nu_c(C\cup D)=0$.